# Batch Script - First "IF" selection does not work, rest do

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am having trouble with my code. If I run the file and follow the prompt, enter a workstation name then select site 1, it continues to open up the cmd window to execute the psexec command, it does not do the "IF NOT EXIST" for site 1, but for other sites it comes back fine. If no file exists it will output to the prompt, if it does it continues to psexec. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

```
:MAN
SET /P S=Please enter a workstation name or IP: 
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Site 1
ECHO 2 - Site 2
ECHO 3 - Site 3
ECHO 4 - Site 4
SET /P D=Select which Site you want to deploy from: 
IF %D%==1 SET D="\\site1\Operations\Sofware\Packages\file.msi"
IF %D%==2 SET D="\\site2\Operations\Sofware\Packages\file.msi"
IF %D%==3 SET D="\\site3\Operations\Sofware\Packages\file.msi"
IF %D%==4 SET D="\\site4\Operations\Sofware\Packages\file.msi"
IF NOT EXIST %D% GOTO MSG

START CMD /K PsExec.exe @%S% -s -h cmd /c msiexec.exe /i "%D%" /qn
PAUSE
GOTO EOF
:MSG
CALL :color 1a "ERROR: MSI PACKAGE DOES NOT EXIST"
```

Comment: Is that your entire batch-file? Because it works perfectly fine for me. Please not that `goto EOF` should be `goto :EOF` by the way, as you can see [here](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)

Comment: This is not my entire script, its just a section of the script, the rest of this script does not need this part and this part does not need the rest of the script. goto EOF has been working fine for me though.

Comment: Are the names of the different sites the ones you show here? it could be an error with their names.

Comment: I should add that i have :EOF in another part of the script, so once it finishes executing, it should jump to :EOF

Comment: Than you can disregard my message about that, although you're better off not using EOF as a labelname, since it already is something.

Comment: Yes the folder names are different, I will try a different folder location to see if that is it.

Comment: If you edit your question with the correct foldernames, I could try to continue helping, although trying that for yourself is always better.

Comment: I put the locations I have in my script, although if I add another IF statment before the first 1. the first one works and not the second one. Example:       IF %D%==0 SET D="\\10.1.3.3\Operations\Sofware\Packages\quest.msi"
IF %D%==1 SET D="\\10.1.3.3\Operations\Sofware\Packages\quest.msi"
IF %D%==2 SET D="\\10.2.2.1\Operations\Sofware\Packages\quest.msi"
IF %D%==3 SET D="\\10.3.2.1\Operations\Sofware\Packages\quest.msi"
IF %D%==4 SET D="\\10.4.2.1\Operations\Sofware\Packages\quest.msi"

Comment: Are you sure all of the files exist?

Comment: Dennis, the files do not exist for any location for the purpose of testing the message.

Comment: I will also take your advice and change EOF as a labelname

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the : of the line before it? Try SET /P "D=Select which Site you want to deploy from: ", so with double quotes

Comment: Well I certainly feel dumb, so I did have a file in Site 1, which is why it did not output the not exist message, second I have quotes around %D%, so when it executed psexec it was telling me could not find the file.

Comment: I should have looked when you asked me if the files were there....

Comment: The quotes in the if -> set should indeed be around the =, so set "var=value", not set var="value"

Comment: I will try the changes when I get back to the office, thank you.

Comment: no reason to feel dumb, everybody makes mistakes.

Comment: OK I am still having an issue with %D%, saying that the system cannot find the file specified, with out without quotes.

Comment: Using `:EOF` as label name is very dangerous; note that `goto EOF` jumps to that label but `goto :EOF` _always_ jumps to the end of the script, independent on whether or not a label `:EOF` is defined somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working code, there was an issue with PsExec as well not taking the %s% variable, I instead outputted the user input to a text file and had Psexec read from that file. I also edited with everyone's suggestions. Thank you all.

```
:MAN
@ECHO OFF
SET /P S=Please enter a workstation name or IP: 
ECHO %S% >> man.txt
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Site 1
ECHO 2 - Site 2
ECHO 3 - Site 3
ECHO 4 - Site 4
SET /P D=Select which Branch you want to deploy from: 
IF %D%==1 SET "R=\\site1\Operations\Sofware\Packages\file.msi"
IF %D%==2 SET "R=\\site2\Operations\Sofware\Packages\file.msi"
IF %D%==3 SET "R=\\site3\Operations\Sofware\Packages\file.msi"
IF %D%==4 SET "R=\\site4\Operations\Sofware\Packages\file.msi"
IF NOT EXIST %R% GOTO MSG
START CMD /k "PsExec.exe @man.txt -s -h cmd /c msiexec.exe /i %R% /qn & DEL man.txt"
PAUSE
GOTO MENU
:MSG
CALL :color 1a "ERROR: MSI PACKAGE DOES NOT EXIST"
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the possibility of doing:

```
goto label%D%
```

You can also almost do:

```
set D=\\10.%D%.2.1\Operations\Sofware\Packages\quest.msi
```

instead of the 4 IF-statements.

Comment: This would not work for all the path locations, just 3 of the 4 :(

Comment: @MPineda Yes, you must refine a little bit, but that's not hard.

Answer (score -1):

== is not advised in a .bat, .cmd file; I'd use EQU

Comment: Since the other parts of the question use test/dummy variables, it might be that he actually wants to compare strings, in which case EQU doesn't work. Also, that isn't an answer for his problem, so it should be put in the comments.

Comment: Comments seem to require >= 50 rep score; otherwise, I would've put it there.

Comment: `==` enforces string comparison, `EQU` (or similar) does numeric comparison in case both expressions are purely numeric; if there are quotation marks around both expressions (like `if "%varA%" EQU "%varB%"`), `EQU` does a string comparison as well (the `""` are included for comparing too); in case any of the expressions might be empty, you should always use the `""`; in this specific case where we are comparing `set /P` user input which might be empty, I strongly recommend to use `""`, and so, `==` and `EQU` are totally equivalent here...

Comment: I am curious if its an issue of how the script is being called. Calling a script might require an additional %